# shopify: Add a additional questionnaire form at home page and display products based on answer

Tags: shopify, liquid

We want to popup an questionnaire form when user visit our shopify site. After user answer questions in the form, we will recommand products to users based on their answer.

We want to recommand products as different package. For example, product A, B, C is a recommanded package.

What is the best practise to achieve this? I am a web developer and I know liquid language.

Comment: Using JavaScript to build the recommended product links should work..

Comment: I want to use Collection to represent Package, and yes, I will generate the link to those collection page by javascript. and I will fetch package(collection) information by url param.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to make a few different collections for each group of products. Use jquery to select the products and then get them via ajax. Using something like...

```
var collectionName = "selection from popup"

$.ajax({
    url: "/collections/"+collectionName+".json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      successCallback(data);
    }
  });
```

Then write a little function to display the results on the page.